# xdebug not working with breakpoints. How can I fix it?

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-8

`xdebug` debugs a single `file` and `project` both. Problem is when I put a `breakpoint` it does not stop at `breakpoint` rather it stops at the very first line and when I press `F8` it moves to the next line, this way I have to press `F8` to move all the way to the end through code.

I am using `PHP 7.0.5`,`xdebug 2.4.0` & 
netbeans 8.1.

This is what it looks like after I start debugging the project.

[image]

**Notice how it's debugging at line 3(green line) while break point is at line 5(read line).**

Comment: under debug option uncheck stop at first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by  @Chetan Ameta in comments, unchecking this solved the problem[image]